# Safe to use commas between statements?

Tags: javascript, expression

Plenty of developers know that when defining variables, it is ok to separate using commas like so:

```
var a = 1,
    b = 2,
    c = 3;
```

but when writing simple statements, is it safe to just use a comma instead of a semi-colon?

```
var a, b, c;

a = 1,    // instead of a = 1;
b = 2,    // b = 2;
c = 3;    // c = 3;
```

when i test in a browser, it works fine. but i can't seem to find usage of this anywhere. is it bad practice?

Comment: It's a little confusing. But yes you can write your code like this, comma operator `,` allows that. But why? `var a = getInfo(), renderInfo(a), alert('123')`.

Answer (score 1):

The `semicolon` is not required in the end of statements in JavaScript, like it is required in languages like C, C++, C#, Java etc. However, it's a good practice at then of a statement we place a semicolon (This is due to the habit that many of us we have acquired writing apps in the aforementioned languages ). On the other hand using a `,` at then end of a statement, despite it works in JavaScript, it brings some confusion. That being said, I think it's a bad practice.

Answer (score 1):

Imperative programming languages make a distinction between *statements* and *expressions*, which roughly correspond to sentences and groups in a natural language like English. This:

```
a = 1, b = 1;
```

is one statement consisting of two expressions separated by comma. In English, this sounds like

```
A cat has a bat, a pig has a wig.
```

On the other side, this

```
a = 1; b = 1;
```

is two statements, and would be two sentences in English:

```
A cat has a bat. A pig has a wig.
```

In this simple example the difference is negligible, but usually you're supposed to express yourself in sentences and not to clump all stuff together in one comma-separated sentence. At some point it will get really silly:

> > The artist is the creator of beautiful things, to reveal art and conceal the artist is art's aim, the critic is he who can translate into another manner or a new material his impression of beautiful things, the highest, as the lowest, form of criticism is a mode of autobiography, those who find ugly meanings in beautiful things are corrupt without being charming, this is a fault.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see the issue with it, other than potentially confusing developers who review it and may think it is a declare statement, change something, and wonder why it doesn't work. But any good linter program will catch issues like that, and of course unit tests will catch them all.

Personally, I don't do that much, I like the old-style (C)

```
var a, b, c;
a = 1;
b = 2;
c = 3;
```

But I think it is just personal preference. And I always run jslint/jshint on my stuff and have extensive unit tests, so....

Answer (score 0):

Technically it is fine.

This is a [variable statement](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-12.2) with initializers:

```
var a = 1, b = 2, c = 3;
```

This is a [variable statement](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-12.2) without initializers, followed by an [expression statement](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-12.4) which is three [comma-ed](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-11.14) [assignment expressions](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-11.13):

```
var a, b, c;
a = 1, b = 2, c = 3;
```

Both are fine.

I would definitely prefer the first one as it has less mind-friction in it. I generally prefer immutable variables so every assignment looks suspicious to me.